# Regex Get a substring from a string nearest to the end

Tags: regex, powershell

I'm trying to get a substring from a string using a powershell script and regex.

For example I'm trying to get a year that's part of a filename.

Example Filename "Expo.2000.Brazilian.Pavillon.after.Something.2016.SomeTextIDontNeed.jpg"
The problem is that the result of the regex gives me "2000" and no other matches. I need to get "2016" matched. Sadly $matches only has one matched instance. Do I have missed something? I feel getting nuts ;)

If $matches would contain all instances found I could handle getting the nearest to end instance with:

```
$Year = $matches[$matches.Count-1]
```

Powershell Code:

```
# Function to get the images year and clean up image information after it.
Function Remove-String-Behind-Year
{
    param
    (
        [string]$OriginalFileName # Provide the BaseName of the image file.
    )
    [Regex]$RegExYear = [Regex]"(?<=\.)\d{4}(?=\.|$)" Regex to match a four digit string, prepended by a dot and followed by a dot or the end of the string.
    $OriginalFileName -match $RegExYear # Matches the Original Filename with the Regex
    Write-Host "Count: " $matches.Count # Why I only get 1 result?
    Write-Host "BLA: " $matches[0] # First and only match is "2000"
}
```

Wanted Result Table:

```
"x.2000.y.2016.z" => "2016" (Does not work)
"x.y.2016" => "2016" (Works)
"x.y.2016.z" => "2016" (Works)
"x.y.20164.z" => "" (Works)
"x.y.201.z" => "" (Works)
```

Comment: Is there any reason why this regex would not work for you: `.*\.(\d{4})\.|$` ?

Answer (score 0):

- PowerShell's `-match` operator only ever finds (at most) *one* match (although multiple *substrings* of that one match may be found with capture groups).
- However, using the fact that quantifier `*` is *greedy* (by default), we can still use that one match to find the *last* match in the input:
  `-match '^.*\.(\d{4})\b'` finds the *longest* prefix of the input that ends in a 4-digit sequence preceded by a literal `.` and followed by a word boundary, so that `$matches[1]` then contains the *last* occurrence of such a 4-digit sequence.

```
Function Extract-Year
{
  param
  (
    [string] $OriginalFileName # Provide the BaseName of the image file.
  )

  if ($OriginalFileName -match '^.*\.(\d{4})\b') {
    $matches[1] # output last 4-digit sequence found
  } else {
    '' # output empty string to indicate that no 4-digit sequence was found.
  }
}

'x.2000.y.2016.z', 'x.y.2016', 'x.y.2016.z', 'x.y.20164.z', 'x.y.201.z' | 
  % { Extract-Year $_ }
```

yields

```
2016
2016
2016
# empty line
# empty line
```